# Rotating (and mirroring) draw lines in a custom node tikz shape?

Tags: tikz-pgf, rotating, scoping

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\pgfdeclareshape{circtest}{ %
  \inheritsavedanchors[from={rectangle}] %
  \inheritbackgroundpath[from={rectangle}] %
  \inheritanchorborder[from={rectangle}] %
  \foreach \x in {center,north,north east,north west,south,south east,south west,east,west}{ %
    \inheritanchor[from={rectangle}]{\x} %
  } %
  \foregroundpath{ %
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointanchor{\tikz@fig@name}{center}} %
    \begin{pgfscope}[ %
        rotate=90, % nope
%         rotate around={90:(0,0)}, % nope
      ] %
      \foreach \angle [count=\xi] in {0,3,...,360} %
      {%
        \draw[ %
          rotate=90, % nope
          color=blue!\xi] (\angle:2cm) -- (\angle:3cm);
      }
    \end{pgfscope} %
  } % end \foregroundpath
} %


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

  \node[circtest] (ctest) at (5,0) {};

  \begin{scope}[ %
      rotate=90, % ok
  %       rotate around={90:(0,0)}, % ok
    ] %
    \foreach \angle [count=\xi] in {0,3,...,360} %
    {%
      \draw[ %
  %         rotate=90, % ok
        color=black!\xi] (\angle:1cm) -- (\angle:2cm);
    }
  \end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: test01.png]

The black ring is the one in `{tikzpicture}`/`{scope}`, and its coordinate system is rotated, as expected. However, using nearly the same syntax in  `\pgfdeclareshape` ends up *not* rotating the coordinate system - which can be seen on the blue ring, which is a node of the custom `circtest` type.

Here basically, I want to specify (eventually) arguments with a dimension of angle, but I'd want my specification of 0 degrees to refer to "12 o'clock", and I'd want the coordinate system to be counterclockwise. I'm aware that in this case, I could just say `\angle+90` inside the `\pgfdeclareshape` - but I'd rather use something like `rotate=90` inside a scope for legibility reasons. Is there a way I could use such a syntax with a custom, `\pgfdeclareshape`d node?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think I got it - instead of using `{pgfscope}`, just use `\pgftransformrotate` - and `\pgftransformyscale{-1}` to mirror; so the code becomes:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\pgfdeclareshape{circtest}{ %
  \inheritsavedanchors[from={rectangle}] %
  \inheritbackgroundpath[from={rectangle}] %
  \inheritanchorborder[from={rectangle}] %
  \foreach \x in {center,north,north east,north west,south,south east,south west,east,west}{ %
    \inheritanchor[from={rectangle}]{\x} %
  } %
  \foregroundpath{ %
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointanchor{\tikz@fig@name}{center}} %
    \pgftransformrotate{90} %
    \pgftransformyscale{-1} %
    \foreach \angle [count=\xi] in {0,3,...,360} %
    {%
      \draw[ %
%           rotate=90, % nope
        color=blue!\xi] (\angle:2cm) -- (\angle:3cm);
    }
  } % end \foregroundpath
} %


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

  \node[circtest] (ctest) at (5,0) {};

  \begin{scope}[ %
      rotate=90, % ok
  %       rotate around={90:(0,0)}, % ok
    ] %
    \foreach \angle [count=\xi] in {0,3,...,360} %
    {%
      \draw[ %
  %         rotate=90, % ok
        color=black!\xi] (\angle:1cm) -- (\angle:2cm);
    }
  \end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

... and the output becomes:

[image: test01a.png]